# I obtained some elevation data from the USGS website and tried importing it into BlenderGIS and SVDesigner (SoilVision). However, I get a weird render

Tags: qgis, 3d-model, blendergis

The first image is rendered on SVDesigner, the second image is rendered on Blender GIS and the third image is the raster file I obtained from the USGS website.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is that DEM data needs to be prepared before being imported into Blender. [This](https://wanderingcartographer.wordpress.com/2019/11/08/making-shaded-relief-with-blendergis-2019/) article details the process for preparing DEMs to open in Blender with BlenderGIS.

Comment: Thank you so much! I will attempt to follow the instructions given in the article and let you know how it goes. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

X and Y coords are in degrees but z in meters. One degree at equator represents 40000km / 360° = 111km and so one meter equal about 0.00001°. You need to reproject you data beforehand.

Comment: Thank you very much! Yes, upon inspection that does seem to have been the problem. I am working on reprojecting the raster now.